# What do spammers gain by signing up as a user?

Tags: users, security, spam

The majority of new user signups I receive on my Wordpress blog look dodgy, with `@someblog.com`, `@somearticle.com`, or `@gmail.com` addresses.

What do they gain by signing up as a new user?

Comment: the ability to spam?

Comment: @One Trick Pony you should post that as an answer. :) Yes; many sites only allow comments from registered users, so by registering, spammers gain the ability to post comments (or, generally more-trusted comments) to a site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some are attempting to leave their links behind, they believe the quantity not quality approach will actual help increase SEO rankings.

The other reason would be affiliate marketing garbage links trying to make a penny.

Answer (score 5):

The reason spammers are creating accounts most of the time is so they can comment regularly on your blog to gain a link to which ever site they are trying to promote. Also they are checking to see if you "allow new user registrations" which opens up a door of exploits they can try in order to inject SQL into your site to add backlinks without your knowledge.

They are running bots that are designed to go out and gather intelligence by targeting Google searches such as “powered by wordpress” & " inurl:wp-login.php. The bot then gives them an insight on to which websites would be open to attack.

Hope this helps!